Holomorphic rotational vector field on \PP^1
On p. 45 of the Mirror Symmetry textbook (Hori-Katz-Klemm-Pandharipande-Thomas-Vafa-Vakil-Zaslow), Example 3.5.1 reads: "On $\mathbb{P}^1$ consider the holomorphic vector field $u \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$... Of course, this vector field is just the generator of a rotation, which has fixed points at the north and south poles." I am confused on how to think of this as a rotation, since this looks more like a radial vector field to me. I would think that $\sqrt{-1}\cdot u \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ would generate a rotational vector field, for instance, because under the identification of $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ as a real-vector space, this can be written as the rotational vector field $\left< -y, x \right>$ in a coordinate chart.
Update: It is possible that since integral curves along this field correspond to $u \mapsto u^2/2$, that this is what is meant by ``generator of a rotation." Still not sure.

This holomorphic vector field looks like the generator of the holomorphic $\mathbb{C}^*$-action on $\mathbb{P}^1$ defined by $\lambda.[x,y]=[\lambda x,y]$. This action indeed has two fixed points, $0$ and $\infty$. If you consider the real and imaginary parts of the vector field, I think that one generates the usual $\mathbb{S}^1$ action on the sphere, while the other is the radial vector field you have in mind. Does this make more sense?

The question is how to think of this as a rotation. The real part of the vector field $u \frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ does not generate the usual $S^1$ action on the sphere -- here, $u$ is the coordinate on, say, $S^2$ minus the north pole. So the real part of this vector field points ``away" from the imaginary axis at all points.
Similarly, the imaginary part of this vector field does not generate the usual $S^1$ action on the sphere. Instead, it points away from the real axis at each point.
So no, that does not make more sense.

If you let $u=x+i y$ (not the same $x$ and $y$ of my previous comment, these are the usual coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$), then what you wrote is an accurate description of $\partial_u$, but $u,\partial_u$ is slightly different. Let me know if you'd prefer me writing a proper answer.

No, I literally mean the real and imaginary parts. Still, I am only telling you what seems to me a possible interpretation of the question. Note that if $u$ is a complex number, then multiplication by $u$ also encodes a rotation! Anyway, $\Re(u\partial_u)=\frac{1}{2}\Re\left((x+i,y)(\partial_x-i,\partial_y)\right)=\frac{1}{2}(x\partial_x+y\partial_y)$, while $\Im(u\partial_u)=\frac{1}{2}(-x\partial_y+y\partial_x)$. This last vector field generates (clockwise) rotations...

Yeah I agree, if this is the interpretation then the text is rather misleading. To answer the question in your last comment, do you have some familiarity with complex differential geometry, for example the first chapters of the Griffiths-Harris book?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
